# Create and populate labels from database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, label

at the moment I'm working on a system where users can input and view comments. The input part works fine, however getting it to display comments is not working.

What I am currently trying to do is for each entry in the comments table, I want the system to create a new label and then populate that label's Text with the date, user name and then the users comment.

I've attached the code I'm below, any input or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Try
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\IMData.mdb;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Comments where ID=@p1"
    cmd.Prepare()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TrackNum.Text)
    Dim Comments = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim labelY = 418
    With Comments
        .Read()
        For Each item In Comments
            Dim newComment As New Label
            newComment.Name = item
            newComment.Left = 983
            newComment.Top = labelY
            newComment.Font = Font
            newComment.Text = .Item("Date") + " " + .Item("User") + " : " + .Item("Comment")
            newComment.Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(newComment)
            labelY += 47
        Next
        .Close()
    End With
    con.Close()
Catch
End Try
```

This is the working code:

```
    Try
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\IMData.mdb;")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Comments where ID=@p1"
        cmd.Prepare()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TrackNum.Text)
        Dim Comments = cmd.ExecuteReader
        With Comments
            .Read()
            Dim labelY = 418
            For Each item In Comments
                Dim newComment As New Label
                newComment.Name = labelY
                newComment.Top = labelY
                labelY += 47
                newComment.Left = 983
                newComment.Font = Font
                newComment.Text = item("Date") + " : " + item("User") + " : " + item("Comment")
                newComment.Width = 900
                newComment.Visible = True
                Me.Controls.Add(newComment)
            Next
            .Close()
        End With
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of errors here and because it is in a try,catch with no output on the catch you are not seeing the issue.

See comments below for corrections:

```
Try
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\IMData.mdb;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Comments where ID=@p1"
    cmd.Prepare()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TrackNum.Text)
    Dim Comments = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim labelY = 418
    With Comments
        .Read()
        For Each item In Comments
            Dim newComment As New Label
            newComment.Name = item 'this needs to be a string such as item("ID") - must be unique!'
            newComment.Left = 983
            newComment.Top = labelY
            newComment.Font = Font
            newComment.Text = .Item("Date") + " " + .Item("User") + " : " + .Item("Comment")
                              'these 'Item's should not have the period in front of them'
            newComment.Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(newComment)
            labelY += 47
        Next
        .Close()
    End With
    con.Close()
Catch
'add in something to catch the error such as console.writeline'
End Try
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get this working... I've changed .Name = item("ID") to labelY (So that it's unique, all the ID's are the same) and removed the periods but I can't get it to work still. I'd like to catch what's being captured by Comments to see what ExecuteReader is getting, but I don't know how to get that working either...

Comment: if you add `ex As Exception` after catch (same line) you can then use console.writeline(ex.tostring) OR (wait for the objections...) msgbox(ex.tostring) which will show you where the error is OR (wait for the explosions...) for debugging comment out the try,catch altogether!

Comment: Thanks OSKM! The error I'm getting is System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "Wo311110414" to type 'Double' is not valid. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Did it indicate which line the error was on?  Incidentally it would be more normal for an ID to be unique

Comment: Managed to get it to work. It needed .Width to be defined? I'm going to edit above with the working code in a minute.